# how to get the container inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent-child

I have used the below code to get the container for the

```
<div id="dvContainer" class="page-container">
    <header class="clearfix">
    </header>
</div>
```

I get the container using below code

```
var container = '#dvContainer header';
```

How can I get the container which is a div

```
<div id="dvContainer">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here I want to get the container `<div class="content-wrapper">`

how do i get this?

Comment: what do you want  ?? expected output briefly

Comment: What do you want "content-wrapper" or div's inside "content-wrapper" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this

```
var container = '#dvContainer .content-wrapper';
```

Comment: This simply sets `container` to a string.  It doesn't search the DOM for the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right:

```
#dvContainer .content-wrapper div
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var container = $('#dvContainer');
```

It will return the reference to

```
<div id="dvContainer" class="page-container"></div>
```

you can check it by using

```
console.log(container.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Do you want the `dvContainer` or one of the `<div>`s inside of it?

If you want `<div id="dvContainer">`:

```
var container = $('#dvContainer');
```

Or the `<div class="content-wrapper>`:

```
var container = $('#dvContainer .content-wrapper');
```

Or the div inside of `<div class="content-wrapper>`:

```
var container = $('#dvContainer .content-wrapper div');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the div with class 'content-wrapper'

```
var container = $('#dvContainer div.content-wrapper');
```

Or if you want the div within the div with class 'content-wrapper'

```
var container = $('#dvContainer div.content-wrapper div');
```

or if you want just the div with id 'dvContainer'

```
var container = $('#dvContainer');
```